# inconsistent page numbering position of glossaries page in toc

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I am preparing a thesis using `book` document class and some package for fulfilling the requirement of university dissertation page layout, such as the roman page number is supposed to be at the up right corner. And I use `glossaries` package to generate a list of abbreviation and insert it after the list of figures. However, the content is good, but the page number is in the middle bottom, instead of up right corner.

Below is part of `thesis.sty`, which I assume is responsible for page number positioning.

```
\renewcommand{\ps@myheadings}{
% Since the default margin is 1'' we move up .25 in for a page number
% at 3/4'' from the top.
  \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{ \thepage}
% For twosided, 'even' are the left side pages.
% For onesided, Only 'odd' is used -- the right side pages are all of them.
  \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{ \thepage}

  \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{}
  \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{}
}
```

The other contents, like `\listoftables`, are all good, and `tocloft` package is used to insert them into TOC.

I also tried to use `\thispagestyle{myheadings}` and/or `\clearpage` to confine the `\printglossaries` command, but no luck. 
Problem solved, and below is the MWE:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
   %
   \usepackage{thesis} % some format specifications define page number in up right corner
   \usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries} % loaded after hyperref

   \newacronym{cvd}{CVD}{chemical vapor deposition}
   \newacronym{cft}{CFT}{crystal-field theory}

   \makeglossaries

\begin{document}

  \title{\LaTeX is great}
  \author{me}
  \maketitle

    \clearpage
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \listoftables
    \clearpage
    \listoffigures

    \begin{singlespace}
    %\thispagestyle{myheadings} % before, this does not work
    \renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\thispagestyle{myheadings}} % after, this works. 
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
    \clearpage
    \end{singlespace}

    \include{./ch-intro/ch-intro}

   %\glsaddallunused
    \appendix
    \chapter{math}
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
    \begin{singlespace}
    \printbibliography
    \end{singlespace}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more info, possibly a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: `\printglossaries` is probably starting a new (implicit) chapter, which is calling `\pagestyle{plain}`, which would put a page number at the bottom of the page in the centre.  But without an MWE, as was suggested, it is just a guess.

Comment: You could try `\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\thispagestyle{myheadings}}` before `\printglossaries`

Comment: thanks, Nicola. It works! and I added a MWE into the main question to make it clear to others. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

(Converting my comment into an answer.)

You can set the page style as appropriate in the glossary preamble by redefining `\glossarypreamble` somewhere before `\printglossaries`. For example:

```
\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\thispagestyle{myheadings}}
```